# Como usar teclas direcionais, como para cima, para baixo, do teclado para navegar uma lista de botões?

Tags: java, swing

Tenho esses botões implementados com clique do mouse, só que eu queria o seguinte: que eu pudesse navegar por eles através das **teclas de direção** ***subir e descer*** e que entrasse através do **enter**. Alguém sabe como implementa? São os botões: **btIniciar, btSobre e btSair**.

Eu sei que o certo sera eu ter alguma coisa feita para vocês ajudarem, mas eu só tenho feito o `ActionListener` dos botões. As ações de teclado eu realmente não sei como usar.

Segue o código que tenho:

```
package ju;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Botoes extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JButton btIniciar;
private JButton btSobre;
private JButton btSair;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Botoes frame = new Botoes();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Botoes() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    btIniciar = new JButton("Iniciar");
    btIniciar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("foi clicado");
        }
    });
    btIniciar.setBounds(146, 101, 125, 37);
    contentPane.add(btIniciar);

    btSobre = new JButton("Sobre");
    btSobre.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("foi clicado");
        }
    });
    btSobre.setBounds(146, 156, 125, 37);
    contentPane.add(btSobre);

    btSair = new JButton("Sair");
    btSair.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    btSair.setBounds(145, 213, 126, 37);
    contentPane.add(btSair);
}
}
```

Coloquei no meu código, mas não deu certo (rodei esse q vc mandou e deu certo, mas mandei só um esboço). Será que é pelo jeito que estão os meu botões? deem uma olhada como é de fato meu código.

```
package visao;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import controle.Constantes;


public class TelaInicial extends JFrame {

    private JPanel painelTI;
    private boolean seJogando;
    private JButton btIniciarTI;
    private JButton btSobreTI;
    private JButton btSairTI;

    private JLabel lblImgTelaInicialTI;
    private JLabel lblTextNomeDoJogo;
    public static int coluna=0;
    JPanel p1;

    public TelaInicial() {

        setFocusable(true);
        setUndecorated(true);   
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize( Constantes.ALTURA, Constantes.LARGURA);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        painelTI = new JPanel();
        painelTI.setLayout(null);
        setContentPane(painelTI);

        lblTextNomeDoJogo = new JLabel("");
        lblTextNomeDoJogo.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblTextNomeDoJogo.setFont(GerenciarFonte.FontePlain(47));
        lblTextNomeDoJogo.setBounds(242, 250, 633, 46);
        painelTI.add(lblTextNomeDoJogo);

        btIniciarTI = new JButton("Iniciar");
        btIniciarTI.setFont(GerenciarFonte.FontePlain(44));
        btIniciarTI.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btIniciarTI.setFocusable(false);
        btIniciarTI.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btIniciarTI.setFocusPainted(true);
        btIniciarTI.setBounds(445, 350, 185, 47);
        painelTI.add(btIniciarTI);


        btSobreTI = new JButton("Sobre");
        btSobreTI.setFont(GerenciarFonte.FontePlain(42));
        btSobreTI.setForeground(Color.WHITE);//laranja 255 69 0
        btSobreTI.setFocusable(false);
        btSobreTI.setBorderPainted(true);
        btSobreTI.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btSobreTI.setFocusPainted(true);
        btSobreTI.setBounds(461, 414, 156, 41);
        painelTI.add(btSobreTI);

        btSairTI = new JButton("Sair");
        btSairTI.setFont(GerenciarFonte.FontePlain(42));//RockoUltraFLF
        btSairTI.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btSairTI.setFocusable(false);
        btSairTI.setBorderPainted(true);
        btSairTI.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btSairTI.setFocusPainted(true);
        btSairTI.setBounds(471, 472, 131, 37);
        painelTI.add(btSairTI);

        OrdenadorDeFoco of = new OrdenadorDeFoco(this);
        of.configurarOrdem(btIniciarTI, btSobreTI, btSairTI);

        lblImgTelaInicialTI = new JLabel();
        lblImgTelaInicialTI.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagem/11.jpg")));
        lblImgTelaInicialTI.setBounds(0, 0,Constantes.ALTURA, Constantes.LARGURA);
        painelTI.add(lblImgTelaInicialTI);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawRect(436, 341, 201, 58);
        g.drawRect(436, 408, 201, 47);
        g.drawRect(436, 463, 201, 47);
    }


    public class Panel extends JGradientPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);


            g.setColor(new Color(255,69,0));
            g.draw3DRect( 414, 273, 180, 37, true );

            g.draw3DRect( 414, 363, 180, 37, true );

            g.draw3DRect( 414, 453, 180, 37, true ); 
        }


        public Panel(Color initialColor, Color finalColor) {
            super(initialColor, finalColor);
        }
    }

    public JButton getBtIniciarTI() {
        return btIniciarTI;
    }

    public JButton getBtSairTI() {
        return btSairTI;
    }

    public JButton getBtSobreTI() {
        return btSobreTI;
    }

    public boolean isSeJogando() {
        return seJogando;
    }

    public void setSeJogando(boolean seJogando) {
        this.seJogando = seJogando;
    }

}
```

```
package visao;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GerenciarFonte {

public Font carregarFonte(String caminho, int tipo, int tamanho) {
    Font minhaFonte = null;

    try {

        minhaFonte = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResourceAsStream(caminho)).deriveFont(tipo,
                tamanho);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    } catch (FontFormatException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    return minhaFonte;
}

public static Font FontePlain(int tamanho){
    GerenciarFonte f = new GerenciarFonte();
    Font cooper = f.carregarFonte("/fonte/cooper-black.ttf", Font.PLAIN, tamanho);
    return cooper;
}

public static Font FonteBold(int tamanho){
    GerenciarFonte f = new GerenciarFonte();
    Font cooper = f.carregarFonte("/fonte/cooper-black.ttf", Font.BOLD, tamanho);
    return cooper;
}

public static Font FontePlainListen(int tamanho){
    GerenciarFonte f = new GerenciarFonte();
    Font cooper = f.carregarFonte("/fonte/TypoSlabserif-Light.ttf", Font.BOLD, tamanho);
    return cooper;
}

}
```

```
package visao;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JGradientPanel extends JPanel {
    private Color finalColor;
    private Color initialColor;

public JGradientPanel(Color initialColor, Color finalColor) {
    if (initialColor == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid initial color!");
    if (finalColor == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid final color!");
    this.initialColor = initialColor;
    this.finalColor = finalColor;
}

public void setInitialColor(Color color) {
    this.initialColor = color;
    invalidate();
}

public void setFinalColor(Color color) {
    this.finalColor = color;
    invalidate();
}

public Color getInitialColor() {
    return initialColor;
}

public Color getFinalColor() {
    return finalColor;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    if (!isOpaque()) {
        return;
    }
    GradientPaint paint = new GradientPaint(new Point2D.Float(getWidth() / 2, 0), initialColor,
            new Point2D.Float(getWidth() / 2, getHeight()), finalColor);
    g2d.setPaint(paint);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g2d.dispose();
}
}
```

```
public abstract class Constantes {

public static final int ALTURA = 1000;
public static final int LARGURA = 700;


}
```

essa classe **ordenador de foco** , usando MVC, ela deveria ficar em qual camada?

[image: Botões como quero]

Comment: Então adicione o que fez até agora, em forma de [mcve], pois senão é complicado ajudar. A resposta abaixo pode não resolver o problema, já que keyevent só captura eventos e nao faz navegacao. Se fornecer um exemplo, fica mais facil ajudar.

Comment: Isso é swing, javafx, android (acho que não, mas vai que) ou alguma outra coisa?

Comment: isso é swing. coloquei o código q tenho

Comment: Você só tem os 3 botoes mesmo nessa tela? Não tem outros componentes nao ne?

Comment: Não pode ser com TAB nao? Se for com tab, você não precisa implementar muita coisa. Se for com setas, ai fica mais complicado porque tem que mexer com [Subsistema de foco](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) e é bem chatinho implementar.

Comment: Sem o código das classes `Constantes`, `GerenciarFonte` e `JGradientPanel` e o ícone `"/imagem/11.jpg"` fica mais complicado responder. Tentei chutar os valores das constantes, comentar as linhas do `GerenciarFonte` e do ícone e substituir `JGradientPanel` por `JPanel`, mas o resultado foi apenas uma tela cinza vazia.

Comment: Ah, e por sinal, o `OrdenadorDeFoco` está na camada de visão.

Comment: Ah, chutei valores maiores para as constantes e os botões apareceram.

Comment: coloquei as outras classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que seria algo assim (versão 2.0):

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class OrdenadorDeFoco {

    private static final String UP = "up";
    private static final String DOWN = "down";
    private static final String ENTER = "enter";

    private final Map<Component, Component> upMap = new WeakHashMap<>(20);
    private final Map<Component, Component> downMap = new WeakHashMap<>(20);

    private Component primeiro;

    public OrdenadorDeFoco(JFrame window) {
        this(window, (JComponent) window.getContentPane());
    }

    public OrdenadorDeFoco(JDialog window) {
        this(window, (JComponent) window.getContentPane());
    }

    public OrdenadorDeFoco(JWindow window) {
        this(window, (JComponent) window.getContentPane());
    }

    private OrdenadorDeFoco(Window window, JComponent contentPane) {
        InputMap im = contentPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), UP);
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP, 0), UP);
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), DOWN);
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_KP_DOWN, 0), DOWN);
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), ENTER);

        contentPane.getActionMap().put(UP, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Component este = window.getFocusOwner();
                Component depois = este == null ? null : upMap.get(este);
                if (depois == null) depois = primeiro;
                depois.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });

        contentPane.getActionMap().put(DOWN, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Component este = window.getFocusOwner();
                Component depois = este == null ? null : downMap.get(este);
                if (depois == null) depois = primeiro;
                depois.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });

        contentPane.getActionMap().put(ENTER, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Component este = window.getFocusOwner();
                if (!(este instanceof AbstractButton)) return;
                ((AbstractButton) este).doClick();
            }
        });

        window.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                int k = e.getKeyCode();
                if (k == KeyEvent.VK_UP || k == KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP || k == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || k == KeyEvent.VK_KP_DOWN) {
                    Component agora = window.getFocusOwner();
                    if (agora == null) primeiro.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void configurarOrdem(Component... elementos) {
        int n = elementos.length;
        if (primeiro == null && n > 0) primeiro = elementos[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Component antes = elementos[(i + n - 1) % n]; 
            Component este = elementos[i];
            Component depois = elementos[(i + n + 1) % n];
            upMap.put(este, antes);
            downMap.put(este, depois);
        }
    }
}
```

Essa classe `OrdenadorDeFoco` é responsável por fazer a mágica. No construtor, ela recebe o `JFrame`, `JDialog` ou `JWindow` com o qual ela vai trabalhar. O truque está nos dois `Map`s que mapeiam qual é o botão acima e qual é o botão abaixo de cada outro botão (na verdade, não necessariamente botão, pode ser qualquer componente).

O `InputMap` e o `contentPane.getActionMap()` são utilizados para sequestrar o comportamento padrão das teclas das setas acima e abaixo (inclusive no teclado numérico) e das duas teclas <kbd>enter</kbd> para tomar ações personalizadas com ela.

Após construir uma instância do `OrdenadorDeFoco`, o método `configurarOrdem` é utilizado para ordenar-se os botões. Você pode chamar ele várias vezes com uma mesma instância de um mapeador para aplicar a sequência a vários grupos de botões.

O `KeyAdapter` serve para o caso de o foco estar com a tela sem estar com nenhum de seus componentes, caso em que o primeiro elemento adicionado com `configurarOrdem` receberá o foco.

O [`WeakHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) é utilizado para que componentes que sejam chave do `Map` possam ser coletados como lixo mesmo se estiverem no `Map`. Isso serve para evitar o bug que ocorreria do `OrdenadorDeFoco` impedir a coleta de lixo de componentes que não estão mais em lugar nenhum.

O `OrdenadorDeFoco` é um componente na camada de visão do MVC. O motivo disso é que ele lida diretamente com os componentes da interface gráfica, mas não se preocupa em nada com o que acontece quando você clica em um deles.

Eis aqui uma forma de se usar isso (versão 2.0 também):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class TesteBotoes {

    private static final Color VERDE_FOLHA = new Color(47, 126, 95);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(TesteBotoes::criarTela);
    }

    private static void criarTela() {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Teste");
        jf.setFocusable(true);
        jf.setUndecorated(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        jp.setBackground(VERDE_FOLHA);
        GridLayout g = new GridLayout(3, 1);
        g.setVgap(10);
        jp.setLayout(g);
        JButton btIniciar = criarBotao(jp, "Iniciar", e -> System.out.println("Iniciar"));
        JButton btSobre = criarBotao(jp, "Sobre", e -> System.out.println("Sobre"));
        JButton btSair = criarBotao(jp, "Sair", e -> jf.dispose());
        jf.setContentPane(jp);

        OrdenadorDeFoco of = new OrdenadorDeFoco(jf);
        of.configurarOrdem(btIniciar, btSobre, btSair);

        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setSize(145, 151);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JButton criarBotao(Container pai, String titulo, ActionListener acao) {
        JButton botao = new JButton(titulo);
        botao.setBackground(VERDE_FOLHA);
        botao.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        botao.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE));
        botao.addActionListener(acao);
        pai.add(botao);
        return botao;
    }
}
```

Você pode usar o método `criarBotao` para configurar os botões, inclusive mudar a fonte, a cor, etc. Decidi usar um `GridLayout` ao invés do layout nulo.

Se você usar o `algumBotao.setFocusable(false);`, provavelmente coisas ruins ou estranhas vão acontecer.

Este código do `OrdenadorDeFoco` deve resolver o seu problema por ora, embora eu pessoalmente não tenha gostado muito e acho que ele pode criar outros problemas depois.

Comment: Esse sistema de subfoco é um saco de usar, nunca entendi porque complicaram tanto algo que deveria ser mais simples de se fazer na API.

Comment: Se bem que reparando melhor, você não usou subsistema de foco, usou keybindings. Viajei legal haha

Comment: Quase tudo no `javax.swing` é detestável. rs

Comment: @Gabriel Pois é, o swing é um monstrengo difícil de se trabalhar. Se tivesse sido projetado mais cuidadosamente, prezando por simplicidade e com menos pressa, certamente o Java teria sido difundido no ambiente desktop muito mais do que foi.

Comment: editei minha pergunta

Comment: @Gabriella e não vai funcionar mesmo, você removeu o foco de todos os botoes, se os botôes não podem receber foco, impossivel acessar eles usando teclado. Remova o `setFocusable(false);` de todos os botoes que funcionará;

Comment: removi, mas não teve alteração nenhuma

Comment: @Gabriella Resposta atualizada.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Realmente isso. Agradeço a ajuda. Fique bem!